# Adding a JS banner to WP sidebar

Tags: javascript, wordpress

for my homework i received a task to implement a banner to a wordpress sidebar. Since i have never done this before with these kind of banners i am pretty much lost. How can i add it? Should i somehow add the whole zip file? I am really lost here, this is not my field of work and i would really appreciate your help.

I am adding a screenshot of how the file looks. Also, my school mate created a tracking code, should it be added to the header of the page?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soOhl.png)

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Like what's inside the zip file, what you've already tried and what it turned out like?

Comment: @THess Sorry, i can make it work on one install of wordpress, but the other one in which i have to present my work just doesn't show. Only a blank window appears. I added the code to the original post.